# Home needed/useful as category for BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a Receiver like so in my Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I saw here on StackOPancakes one like so:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootupReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> 
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

What is the purpose/advantage of the "HOME" category assignment?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) we can read that categories like "android.intent.category.HOME" and "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" are used to group activities into some sets. For instance, "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" is used by Launcher application to select applications that can be launch. Similarly, for an intent-filter for an **activity** with category "android.intent.category.HOME" is used to find a home screen.

But with BroadcastReceivers I think this category is used as additional category test.